# Is it possible to use newer headers on an older version of gcc (g++)?

Tags: iphone, c++, gcc, header

Is it possible to use newer headers with an older version of gcc ?
I have gcc 4.2.1 on my ipod (which I learned has a compiler that can be installed with cydia) but I have gcc 4.4.3 on my distro. I was wondering if I need to get the original headers (if thats even possible, I know gnu likes to phase way older versions out) or if I can just use the ones from my distro?

In particular, I'm talking about g++.

EDIT: just found this going to follow it.

[jeremyg:Building c/c++ applications using gcc/g++ on iphone](http://jeremylg.blogspot.com/2009/10/building-cc-applications-using-gccg-on.html)

NEW EDIT:
Found this Trying to compile Hello World example but can't find objc library?
[antirez iphone-gcc tutorial](http://antirez.com/page/iphone-gcc-guide.html)

Edit: Well I'm in one hell of a spot lmao I've got full C support and an almost usable g++ compiler and the open toolchain(torrented a "working version") that needs minor modifications.
if i could just get objc working on my ipod I wouldn't mind using objc the whole purpose is to of course is to make apps :D

one quick question the toolchain was compiled on an amd64 machine but for i686 so that makes it intel compatible? I'm not sure the whole amd64 thing is throwing me off ;P

Comment: hmm seems that C works 100%. C++ however I don't think is fully ported yet. It gives me compile errors when compiling but I know these headers are flawless(well you get the idea) I use them all the time. I've got once last option to try and find the originial 4.0.0 headers

Comment: I'm not familiar with iPod programming, but it is common on small embedded platforms to lack support for various C++ features (exceptions, for example), which makes much of the C++ standard library unusable.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to, there's no reason for the gcc on your PC and on your iPod to be the same. What are you trying to do?

Comment: just set up the STL so I can do what I normally do code :D I'm assuming that the g++ hasn't been fully ported or that you need the 4.0.0 headers I'm trying the latter first. I can say however that C works :D

Comment: @Aquertu: GCC 4.2 had full STL support as well.

Comment: @jalf I know I was just fearing that it might have some major differences that would interfere with compiling(or possibly linking).